# "Visual center" of a concave polygon

Tags: geometry

I have an area I want to place a label within. I'm currently finding the centroid and placing the label there. In the case of a concave polygon, though, often the centroid is actually outside the boundary. In this case, I want to correct the position of the label and place it roughly in the "visual center" of the polygon. This is tricky because I don't even know what I would *define* as the visual center. Perhaps somewhere halfway along the "skeleton".

Is there some kind of calculation I can do? It doesn't have to be the absolute center - just somewhere roughly "in the middle" under some definitions. I've already pre-calculated the centroid if that's useful.

Comment: I think it is quite difficult to give a meaningful and comprehensive definition of this "visual center". What happens, for instance, if the polygon has the shape of a dumbbell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point you're looking for is the [Pole of Inaccessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_of_inaccessibility) of the polygon. It's commonly used to position labels within maps.

One possible approach is the "Polylabel" algorithm, which uses [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to subdivide the polygon until the point can be found:

[image: Polyline algorithm using quadtrees]

The company [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com/) (note: no affiliation) has released an implementation under the ISC License: https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel.