# Better "centerpoint" than centroid for placing a map marker inside a concave region (that may have holes)?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, polygons, centroid

I'm using the centroid of polygons to attach a marker in a map application. This works definitely fine for convex polygons and quite good for many concave polygons.

However, some polygons (banana, donut) obviously don't produce the desired result: The centroid is in these cases *outside* the polygons area.

Does anybody know a better approach to find a suitable point *within* any polygons area (which may contain holes!) to attach a marker?

[image]

*Disclaimer:* This is a cross-post from stackoverflow. I was recommended to re-post it here.

Comment: Try the point at maximum distance from the boundary.

Comment: I seem to recall a question here from not-too-long ago (a couple of months?) that asked about placing labels inside regions. A comment or answer described a strategy used by map-makers. I'm having trouble finding that question at the moment.

Comment: @Rahul: That's probably a good candidate -- but how to find it algorithmically?

Comment: If you want an exact computation for Rahul's suggestion, you could look around the notion of medial axis. There is a bunch of literature around that, including approximate computations. An alternative to the medial axis would be the [straight skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton). It's not really the point at max distance, but it should still be an okay candidate. EDIT: to clarify, you want to look at vertices of the medial axis/straight skeleton.

Comment: I found the previous question: ["Visual center” of a concave polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1500396/409). The answer notes that the map-making term of art for the point you seek is the region's "pole of inaccessibility".